# Ajax call no longer working (401 unauthorized)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

The code below was working perfectly on my branch (and even some commits before) and mysteriously I'm now getting the js message: **401 (Unauthorized)** after I inspect the browser.

I have a autocomplete form and when the user selects one field it needs to send this data to be analyzed by the action "get_location" from the same controller.

**home_form.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  return $("#search_city").on("change", function() {
    return $.ajax({
      url: "home/get_location",
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "script",
      data: {
        city: $('#search_city').val()
      }
    });
  });
```

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :home, only: [:index] do
    get 'get_location', on: :collection
  end
```

**home_controller.rb**

```
require 'recognize_data'

class HomeController < ApplicationController
  layout "home"
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [ :index ]
  include DataX

  def index
  end

  def get_location
    # do some stuff here
  end

end
```

**home.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= action_cable_meta_tag %>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'home/manifest.css', media: 'all' %>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB5LELGIW21xr6W1H1NBQNvjqLM3hENa64&libraries=places&language=pt-BR"></script>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'home/manifest.js' %>
  </head>

<body>

<%= yield %>

<%= yield(:form_js) %>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to authenticate. Maybe your auth token was cached and now it cleared.

Comment: Do you use SPA approach or is it just an ajax call from average multi page authentication? Briefly, do you use token for authentication or standard cookies?

Comment: @zsawaf how can I solve it?

Comment: @AntonTkachov I'm not using any token for authentication...Do I need to generate it manually inside the js code?

Comment: Can you paste full code of home_controller?

Comment: @AntonTkachov sure

Comment: What rails version do you use?

Comment: Should get_location work for none authenticated user?

Comment: @AntonTkachov the problem is solved now...thank you a lot for your effort to help! I just missed ' });' to close the js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two issues with my code:

1- Yes, I forgot to put the last `});` to close the js function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  return $("#search_city").on("change", function() {
    return $.ajax({
      url: "home/get_location",
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "script",
      data: {
        city: $('#search_city').val()
      }
    });
  });
});
```

2 - I was using `skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:index]` on home_controller and it was causing conflicts with the action get_location. So I removed the restriction from the index, and just left the sentence: `skip_before_action :authenticate_user!` to cover all the actions.